# How to solve $F-y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=C$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I meet the equation 
$$
F-y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=C \tag{1}
$$
in brachistochrone, where 
$$
F(y,y')= \frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{\sqrt{2gy}}
$$
$g$ is gravitational acceleration.  And $y(0)=0, y(1)=-1$  (the boundary condition is optionally added by me). How to solve (1) ?

Answer (score 0):

Just take $x=\ln y'$. Then, one has
$$
F-\frac{dF}{dx}=C
$$
that you should be able to solve.